# File paths in NVIDIA Isaac Sim (NVIDIA Omniverse)

Tags: nvidia, simulator, nvidia-isaac, omniverse

I am working with the Boston Dynamics quadruped robot, Spot, on NVIDIA Isaac Sim with NVIDIA Orbit. I am trying to replicate the motion of the Unitree A1/Go, which is already present in Isaac Sim's examples along with using a URDF and mesh files of Spot. I am not able to find the location of the files given in the simulator such as `/GroundPlane_01`, `/OmniverseKit_Persp` or even those that refer to the robot I have imported to the sim such as `/spot/base/visuals`, `/spot/fl_uleg/visuals`, etc.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. If anyone can help, may I please know what the location of `/` is in NVIDIA Omniverse? Thank you.

Comment: I believe you will need the Cache installed and the Nucleus service properly setup, since most of the omniverse stuff is under the `://omniverse location`. So you are either missing the files in general or don't have the correct tools for the importing, i.e. the Cache (its an app in the Library section, if installed.)